# Watson assistant putting the day of the week in a variable based on user input of @sys-date

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm making a bot that can take dinner reservations. When it asks for the users reservation time, I'd like the bot to populate my variable $dayoftheweek with the day of the week based on the date the user inputs. How would I be able to do that?

[image: slot]

here is my slot "If Found".

[image: value]
 Basically I'd like to know what "value" I could put in to get the day of the week populated.

Comment: What does the user provide, a date or some text? Do you already have the date entity produced by WA? What definition of "day of week" do you use (ISO, US, ...)?

Comment: the user puts in a @sys-date, Watson normally formats it as YYYY-MM-DD. Then I'd like the value of the $daysoftheweek is able to take that date and determine the day of the week like "monday" for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to use the [new system entities (currently in beta)](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-beta-system-entities). Enable the beta in your skills options. Then, in your dialog node, assign the following:

```
Check for: @sys-data.day_of_week
save as: mydayofweek
```

Note that the day names are lower case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [reformatDateTime](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-dates-reformatDateTime) of the [expession language](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods) to get the day from @sys-date.

For example setting `$dayofweek` to

```
<? @sys-date.reformatDateTime('u') ?>
```

will set `$dayofweek` to a value between "1" (Monday) and "7" (Sunday)

or setting `$dayofweek` to

```
<? @sys-date.reformatDateTime('E') ?>
```

will set `$dayofweek` to a value between "Mo" and "Su"

Answer (score 0):

The value of @sys-date is stored as a string format "yyyy-MM-dd" e.g. "2016-11-21".

If you want to know what day of the week that date is, you can use the method [reformatDateTime](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-dates-reformatDateTime):

```
"<? @sys-date.reformatDateTime('EEEE') ?>"
```

[Here all the posibles values of the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text)

So your node would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEZ5d.png).

Or in JSON format:

```
{
  "context": {
    "dayoftheweek": "<? @sys-date.reformatDateTime('EEEE') ?>"
  }
}
```

And here a small [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhLYw.png) of what would be stored in $dayoftheweek:

> Watson: Hello. How can I help you?
>
> User: Day of the week test
>
> Watson: Tell me a date
>
> User: September 13, 2019
>
> Watson: Friday

[Here](http://s3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/stackoverflow-content-shared/skill-Test-Day-of-The-Week.json) is the JSON Skill for the test.